# N-ary (NOT binary) Gentle Boost algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, classification

I know Gentle Boost, an adaption of the AdaBoost algorithm, can be used for *binary* classification. However, I need to do $n$-ary classification. How do I modify or extend the GentleBoost algorithm so it can be used for $n$-ary classification?

Comment: If you're looking for an implementation, this isn't the place to ask. If you're trying to build one, this can be a good place to ask — feel free to ask questions about algorithms here (but coding questions go to [so]).

Comment: Alright then I've edited the question.

Comment: @Gilles, I edited the question to make it more appropriate for this site (by making it about algorithms, not code) -- I suspect it can be re-opened now.

Comment: I suggest trying at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/